# show that $ [F^{\times}: N_{K/F}(K^{\times})]=n$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $F$ be a finite algebraic extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Let $K$ is an abelian extension of $F$ of degree $n$, then show that $$ [F^{\times}: N_{K/F}(K^{\times})]=n,$$ where $N_{K/F}$ denotes the norm.

I have no idea to prove it but I have got a result as follows:

For an extension $L1$ of the the field $L2$, the norm $N_{L1/L2}$ of $(L1)^{\times}$ is given by 
$$ N_{L1/L2}((L1)^{\times}) \subset (L2)^{\times}.$$

Comment: @user714237, can you justify your word here please?

Comment: @user714237 I believe the highly non-trivial part is the existence of the extension, given its norm subgroup. The direction in this question is a bit easier.

Comment: Can you at least show you understand how to prove it when $K = F(\zeta_n), p\nmid n$

Comment: @reuns, the main problem i am facing is to look at $N(K^{\times})=N((F(\zeta_n))^{\times})$. How to understand the norm of the field of units

Comment: @user714237 We are talking about different approaches. For me, the current question follows directly from the fact that the Artin reciprocity map gives an isomorphism between $\operatorname{Gal}(K/F)$ and $F^\times/N_{K/F}K^\times$. To show the existence of a $K$ corresponding to a given subgroup of $F^\times$ requires some extra work.

Comment: @user714237 Why is it circular? For me the Artin map goes from $\hat H^{-2}(G, \Bbb Z)$ to $\hat H^0(G, K^\times)$, which is taking cup product with a fundamental class. The fact that it is an isomorphism comes from the "class field theory axioms", which themselves are some computations of Brauer groups. I didn't claim that it is trivial, but can you point out why it is circular?

Comment: @user714237 You may think anyway you like. Calling other people's approach "not an approach" or calling other people's comment "twaddle" is not earning you any reputation. I regret having discussed with you.

Comment: @WhatsUp, I know to calculate norm a point of a field but not familiar with the calculation of norm of a set i.e., $N(K^{\times}) = ?$. Can you help me with idea?

Comment: You should have a look at "local class field theory" (e.g. on wiki).

Comment: @WhatsUp, I have folloing, but can ou at least hint?